# Hide 'by' group titles in ODS output

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I'm trying to hide the titles for each by group in my ODS output.  Code:

```
ods noproctitle;
ods html ;

proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
  by sex;
run; 

proc freq data=class;
  by sex;
  tables sex / list;
run;
```

Specifically, the titles I'm trying to hide are:

> Sex=F

and

> Sex=M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the BYLINE/NOBYLINE option.

```
options nobyline;
```

Here's the documentation reference
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lesysoptsref/69799/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1hr2wb7h5g6twn1gtt5r4zjsg39.htm

Comment: Argh, my google-fu failed me.  Thanks... I had assumed the option was related to the proc, ODS, or the by statement somehow.  I never thought to look at the regular options.  Also, I'd rather not say how much time I spent looking for this =P

Comment: I recalled the name, but I expected to find it under ODS as well and it took me a while to find the reference. And I found it only because I knew to look for that term in the first place!